# Attempting (and failing) to install Locomotive CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, locomotivecms

I'm trying to install Locomotive CMS on a virtual rackspace server using their multisite option. I get as far as running the installation and choosing my first subdomain with no problems. But once I create this, the subdomain address gives a 404 error and the root domain give me a 'No site!' error!

I've set up the records in /etc/hosts and am using Unicorn. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [pow](http://pow.cx/) (along with the powify gem) to setup your hosts. Works a breeze!

Comment: Just a note for anyone else finding this answer, it's for OS X only and suitable best for local development.